# Data not binding issue in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-promise, angular-services

I'm new to angular 2 and in my component's `ngOnInit()` I'm calling a service to get some data. This is my component `ngOnInit()` code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Model } from './model';
import { CustomizeModelService } from './customize-model.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-customize-model',
    templateUrl: './customize-model.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./customize-model.component.scss']
})
export class CustomizeModelComponent implements OnInit {

    models = [];

    constructor(private custModelService: CustomizeModelService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        let params = JSON.stringify({
            "query": "{models(modelname: \"TestModel\") {_id, modelname, description}}"
        });
        this.custModelService.getModelByName(params).subscribe(data => {
            this.models.push(data);
            console.log(this.models);
        });
    }

}
```

It returns the data, but in my templates when I interpolate the data, it doesn't show anything

```
<h3 class="title">{{models.modelname}}</h3>
```

I'm not sure where did I make the mistake, or why the data is not getting bound to the template, Any help will be highly appreciated. Any more code required, I can provide

TIA

Comment: Can you show the whole template? Models is an array so it will not have model properties directly on it. Instead you would have to use *ngFor to iterate over each model in the array. also `this.models.push(data));` will add data as a single item to models.

Comment: @JayChase, Please check the question, I updated the full template code

Comment: @JayChase Thanks for your suggestions about *ngFor, not sure why I forgot it in the first place, and now it works. Thanks

Comment: @Mujahid.No problem. I'll move the comment to an answer so you can mark it and close off the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Models is an array so it will not have model properties directly on it. Instead you would have to use *ngFor to iterate over each model in the array.

Also

```
  this.models.push(data));
```

will add data as a single item to models.

Answer (score 1):

In Angular 2 Each Http service method returns an [Observable](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html#!#observables) of HTTP Response objects so you have to subscribe for its response as below :

```
this.custModelService.getModelByName(params).subscribe(data => {
  this.models.push(data);
  console.log(this.models);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion with the Observable, I converted my code to Observables and with the @JayChase suggestion of *ngRepeat, now the code is working.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `*ngIf` to make sure the data which from api is ready for use in html.   like this `<h3 *ngIf="models" class="title">{{models.modelname}}</h3>`. without `*ngIf`, use `models.modelname` in template before api service finish will be raised an error, but after some seconds, the data will be show when refresh page.  console.log is the same.